# How we can single time sign in on facebook in android application?

Tags: android, facebook

In my android device have four application which is used Facebook API, now login one application Facebook and minimize that application and using other application which have also Facebook API,now i want direct login in this application, which i am using previous one,i don,t need again login..

any one have any idea than suggest me..

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Every app will have its own App ID on Facebook and you will have to authenticate each app as they will generate their own access_token upon authentication. That said, once authenticated, it will remain that way until the access_token expires. I have personally never heard of such an implementation. Do correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

since the android environment runs every app on it's very own sandbox, there is absolutely no way of signing in to Facebook from one app to the other and it must be done in every app for itself.

the Facebook SSO is built in to the SDK. the code to achieve it is as follows:

```
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APPID);

facebook.authorize(SinglePost.this, {PERMISSIONS},
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // control comes here if the login was successful
                        // Facebook.TOKEN is the key by which the value of
                        // access token is stored in the Bundle called
                        // 'values'
                        Log.d("COMPLETE", "AUTH COMPLETE. VALUES: "
                                + values.size());
                        Log.d("AUTH TOKEN",
                                "== " + values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
                        updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK ERROR",
                                "FB ERROR. MSG: " + e.getMessage()
                                        + ", CAUSE: " + e.getCause());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "AUTH ERROR. MSG: " + e.getMessage()
                                + ", CAUSE: " + e.getCause());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("CANCELLED", "AUTH CANCELLED");
                    }
                });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult");
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: This is the normal process of using SSO in your app. The OP is asking for 3 apps authenticating on signing in to just one app (a total of 4).

Comment: @SiddharthLele well, since every app runs in it's own sandbox, there is no contact between them and every app has to sign on on itself

Comment: Exactly. The whole premise of this question is kinda un-doable. I have commented saying the same in the OP. It simply can't be done.

Comment: but here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/ they  already mention ..it's possible to get single Sign On.

Comment: @Shubh, SSO means that you sign in and then the Facebook SDK will use that sign on for the rest of the apps, you still have to create a request and a mobile app for posting. use the code in my answer to achieve that